# Bootstrap Progress Bar with Safari

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for progress bars that are non-determinate. They work fine in Chrome and Firefox without any issues. On the page load I hide them and then when a button is clicked it references an on click event for a function that shows the progress bar and then submits the form. I have tried to upgrade bootstrap to version 3 but it still doesn't work in Safari.

```
$("#progress").hide();

function progress(){
    $(function() {

        $("#progress").show();
        });

    document.forms["input"].submit();
}
```

Comment: Safari for windows or Mac?

Comment: I'm using Mac for the test.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with showing/animating the bootstrap progress bar before submitting a form. I solved this by using setTimeout() to call the submit action after showing the progress bar (anything over 300 works).

This is something to do with Safari not rendering any updates to the page after a redirect, like in the case of a form post. It seems to be the only browser that does this:

[Safari not activating css rule on jquery submit action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398490/safari-not-activating-css-rule-on-jquery-submit-action)

[Safari pauses all animation on redirect / form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749519/safari-pauses-all-animation-on-redirect-form-submission)

[progressbar updates blocked in safari while submitting a form](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/progressbar-updates-blocked-in-safari-while-submitting-a-form)

Using setTimeout() works, but Safari will cut the animation after the timeout period, when the form submits. You can use a slightly higher timeout period to create a better illusion of an upload on Safari (the animation keeps working during post on every other browser).