# Safari not activating css rule on jquery submit action

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I have i script theres listing on the submit off the form on the site.

```
$(".movieSearch").submit(function() {
    $("body").addClass("tmdbsearching");
});
```

This script as you can see, will set a class on the body wich then will activate a css overlay rule.

```
div.overlay {
position: fixed;
z-index: 900;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;

-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.89,.005,.545,1);
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.89,.005,.545,1);
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.89,.005,.545,1);
     -o-transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.89,.005,.545,1);
        transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.89,.005,.545,1);
}

body.tmdbsearching div.overlay {
z-index: 900;
opacity: 1 !important;
visibility: visible !important;
}
```

But this donst work Safari will not show the overlay. All other browser it works in. I can safari will set the class on the body, but will not activate the css rule.

i made a test button, to test the overlay. And that works fine.

```
$('.testbutton').click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("tmdbsearching");
});
```

the link to the site is: http://moovee.dk/beta/index.php/tilfoj-film

then you can see in action.

Comment: Try cancelling the submit event and submit using JavaScript after little delay.

Comment: I had that idea in the beginnig but did not find a way to submit a form. So how would go about doing that?

Comment: Try `$(".movieSearch").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $("body").addClass("tmdbsearching"); var that = this; setTimeout(function(){ that.submit(); }, 1); });`

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. Submit as answer and i will set it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding class inside the submit function and submitting the form triggers navigation to another page. In this case, the browser may or may not choose to update the display.

You can workaround this situation as follows:

- Cancel the submit function
- Add class to the body
- Trigger the submit event manually using `setTimeout()`

```javascript
$(".movieSearch").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").addClass("tmdbsearching");
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.submit();
    }, 1);
});
```

In the above example, the submit handler cancels the event and return control to the browser, allowing it to update the display.